# Knex.js columns referencing foreign keys don't get created during migration

Tags: javascript, knex.js

When I execute my knex.js migration, everything builds except my two foreign key tables in the 'recipe-ingredient' join table below.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  It's the third table in the migration:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.hasTable('recipe').then((exists) => {
            console.log('does knex have recipe table?', exists);
            if (!exists) {
                return knex.schema.createTable('recipe', (table) => {
                    table.uuid('id');
                    table.string('name');
                    table.string('description');
                })
            }
        }),
        knex.schema.hasTable('ingredient').then((exists) => {
            console.log('does knex have ingredient table?', exists);
            if (!exists) {
                return knex.schema.createTable('ingredient', (table) => {
                    table.uuid('id');
                    table.string('name');
                })
            }
        }),
        knex.schema.hasTable(`recipe-ingredient`).then((exists) => {
            console.log('does knex have recipe-ingredient table?', exists);
            if (!exists) {
                return knex.schema.createTable(`recipe-ingredient`, (table)=> {
                    table.uuid('recipe_id').references('id').inTable('recipe').notNull();
                    table.uuid('ingredient_id').references('id').inTable('ingredient').notNull();
                    table.string('qty');  // <-- chose string instead of int because receipes include qty such as '1/3 cup', '1 teaspoon', etc.
                })
            }
        })
    ])
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.dropTable('recipe-ingredient'),
        knex.schema.dropTable('ingredient'),
        knex.schema.dropTable('recipe')
    ])
};
```

Here's my knexfile.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST_DEV || '127.0.0.1',
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER_DEV,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD_DEV,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME_DEV
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'recipes'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Note that there's nothing too special about the variables in the .env file.  Just basic username, password, and db name.

Comment: Does `console.log('does knex have recipe-ingredient table?', exists);` execute? What is the value of `exists`?

Comment: @therobinkim great question.  Previously those logs printed true, now they all print false:
```does knex have recipe table? false
does knex have ingredient table? false
does knex have recipe-ingredient table? false```

Migration failing with, ```ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint```

Comment: @therobinkim even though it's getting that fail message, the tables are building, including the foreign key columns, and the seed is working now too!!!

Comment: Which database? In this case that also really might matter.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö I will add my knexfile to the post so you can see.  It's just a local instance of mySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use promise.all and run all the queries parallel.

IIRC knex creates transaction for those queries, but actually mysql is doing implicit commit after first `CREATE TABLE` statement, so transaction will be committed and the rest of the table creations may fail in multiple ways.

Knex may say that it cannot execute more queries to the committed transaction or it might just ignore additional queries or it might just ran them anyways outside of transactions, but through the same database connection. It is hard to say what exactly happens when you run that migration, but definitely it won't do exactly the thing you are hoping for.

This should work better:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.hasTable('recipe').then((exists) => {
        console.log('does knex have recipe table?', exists);
        if (!exists) {
            return knex.schema.createTable('recipe', (table) => {
                table.uuid('id');
                table.string('name');
                table.string('description');
            });
        }
    }).then(() => {
        return knex.schema.hasTable('ingredient').then((exists) => {
            console.log('does knex have ingredient table?', exists);
            if (!exists) {
                return knex.schema.createTable('ingredient', (table) => {
                    table.uuid('id');
                    table.string('name');
                })
            }
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return knex.schema.hasTable(`recipe-ingredient`).then((exists) => {
            console.log('does knex have recipe-ingredient table?', exists);
            if (!exists) {
                return knex.schema.createTable(`recipe-ingredient`, (table)=> {
                    table.uuid('recipe_id').references('id').inTable('recipe').notNull();
                    table.uuid('ingredient_id').references('id').inTable('ingredient').notNull();
                    table.string('qty');  // <-- chose string instead of int because receipes include qty such as '1/3 cup', '1 teaspoon', etc.
                })
            }
        })
    });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('recipe-ingredient')
      .then(() => knex.schema.dropTable('ingredient'))
      .then(() => knex.schema.dropTable('recipe'));
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mikael Lepisto.  Sorry to not return to this thread sooner.  I had to leave this project since then.